# Zoom window in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I've implemented Game of Life using OpenGL buffers (as specified here: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name20). In this implementation each pixel is a cell in the game.

My program receives the initial state of the game (2d array). The size array ,in my implementation, is the size of the window. This of course makes it "unplayable" if the array is 5x5 or some other small values.

At each iteration I'm reading the content of the framebuffer into a 2D array (its size is the window size):

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, win_x, win_y, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Then, I'm doing the necessary steps to calculate the living and dead cells, and then draw a rectangle which covers the whole window, using:

```
glRectf(0, 0, win_x, win_y);
```

I want to zoom (or enlarge) the window without affecting the correctness of my code. If I resize the window, then the framebuffer content won't fit inside image(the array). Is there a way of zooming the window(so that each pixel be drawn as several pixels) without affecting the framebuffer?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag the question as homework.

Comment: @ananthonline The homework tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to be learning opengl 2, I would suggest instead learning a newer version, as it is more powerful and efficient. A good tutorial can be found here http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

If i understand this correctly, you read in an initial state and draw it, then continuously read in the pixels on the screen, update the array based on the game of life logic then draw it back? this seems overly complicated.
The reading of the pixels on the screen is unnecessary, and will cause complications if you try to enlarge the rects to more than a pixel.
I would say a good solution would be to keep a bit array (1 is a organism, 0 is not), possibly as a 2d array in memory, updating the logic every say 30 iterations (for 30 fps), then drawing all the rects to the screen, black for 1, white for 0 using glColor(r,g,b,a) tied to an in statement in a nested for loop.
Then, if you give your rects a  negative z coord, you can "zoom in" using glTranslate(x,y,z) triggered by a keyboard button.

Of course in a newer version of opengl, vertex buffers would make the code much cleaner and efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is a course project. I must implement it the way I did. Is there no way to zoom the window without affecting the framebuffer (or other solutions...?). I'm really loosing my mind on this one.

Comment: hmm...trying to understand what exactly you're trying to do. re-size the window or zoom? if you're re-sizing, you can reset the framebuffer to the new size using the glutReshapeFunc(function) call. to zoom, the framebuffer can stay the same. let's say you have a 10x10 pixel window, so there are 100 rects. now "zoom in", making the 10x10 window now only display 25 rects (each is 2 by 2 now). This would just require dynamic logic, sampling only one pixel in each rect (sample at x intervals, where x is the new rect width), and offset by x, instead of just one when drawing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store your game state directly the window framebuffer and then resize it for rendering, since what is stored in the framebuffer is by definition what is about to be rendered. (You could overwrite it, but then you lose your game state...) The simplest solution would just to store the game state in an array (on the client side) and then update a texture based on that. Thus for each block that was set, you could set a pixel in a texture to be the appropriate color. Each frame, you then render a full screen quad with that texture (with GL_NEAREST filtering).

However, if you want to take advantage of your GPU there are some tricks that could massively speed up the simulation by using a fragment shader to generate the texture. In this case you would actually have two textures that you ping-pong between: one containing the current game state, and the other containing the next game state. Each frame you would use your fragment shader (along with a FBO) to generate the *next state* texture from the *current state* texture. Afterwards, the two textures are swapped, making the *next state* become the *current state*. The *current state* texture would then be rendered to the screen the same way as above.

I tried to give an overview of how you might be able to offload the computation onto the GPU, but if I was unclear anywhere just ask! For a more detailed explanation feel free to ask another question.